# Lock access to plugin options

Tags: plugins, permissions, user-access

While editing a post/page, that item is locked to the current user. How can something similar be accomplished with the settings pages?

Take this for example. admin A is changing settings for a plugin, admin B tries to do the same. OK, this is plugin specific and can be solved by adding a flag to the database/options. But, what if admin A is changing settings for a plugin, and admin B deletes/disables the plugin? Depending on how the plugin was coded, a whole variety of things could go wrong.

Comment: Maybe I miss something but it looks like the answer is in your question, the plugin overrides the functionality of deleting the plugin by admin B the same way it prevents him from editing the settings page

Comment: @MarkKaplun Are you saying that testing the same flag in the `deactivate` handler is sufficient? How does WP handle that with regards to the `active_plugins` array? How can the deactivate be aborted?

Comment: no, I am saying that it is hard to understand what exactly do you ask ;). if there is no appropriate hook then you can check the request parameters early enough to modify their content, would feel like a hack but doable.